# Want to delete Multiple (More than 1000 nodes) nodes of realtime database in firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a game in which, the android app have the chat feature, not i'm storing every single chat text in a 
 child node not that chat node has been created more that 1000 times because of chatting, now i want to delete all the message nodes or say want to provide delete chat feature in my app, what should i do to remove all chat nodes.[Here's my realtime database reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xSKG.jpg)

i have tried this methods
[This method didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbMlt.jpg)

[this also didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inaRX.jpg)

[i don't know why i did this but yeah this worked but for less node if i have 10 or 20 sms its works, but if i tried to delete chat with 1000 sms it shows error like "This request would cause to many function to be triggered"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KUPG.jpg)

i want to delete all the sms nodes which have more node like 1000 or so.

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get better answers. Tell us more about your problem, your platform and how your solution is not working.

Comment: Don't post images with code, please edit your question and add the code as text.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the chat user node you want to delete to 'null'. Something like:

```
mRootRef.child("messages").child(<current_user_node id>).child(<chat_user_node id>).set(null)
```

Comment: Did this solution work for you? If so, please mark the answer as accepted and upvote it. That encourages us to answer your questions next time. Thanks.